# Is Intel HAXM necessary to run Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, haxm

When I try to run Android Studio, I get an error that Intel HAXML is not installed.

I have an AMD A4-3330MX processor. Is Intel HAXML necessary to work with Android Studio? If so, can I use it on an AMD processor?

Comment: The Intel HAXM requires an Intel processor that supports virtualization. Installing or not installing it will make no difference to a computer on an AMD processor. So long story short, you do not need Intel HAXM installed to use Android Studio.

Comment: [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/download) is a popular, free alternative to the native Android emulator

Answer (score 2):

Intel haxm is used for emulator acceleration. If you are on windows and you have an AMD CPU you won't be able to use it. With linux you can use kvm. Refer yourself to [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html) documentation for more informations.

Comment: Okay, so if he can't use it on an AMD CPU, why is he getting this error message? How can he get rid of the error message?